# Does Sitecore 9 OOTB Scheduled Publish publish not only an item but also its child and related items?

Tags: publishing, scheduled-tasks

In Sitecore 7, if I create a scheduled publish on an item, which has children and related items, the item is published correctly, but its child items and related items are not published.

Does Sitecore 9 scheduled publishing publish not only an item but also its child and related items correctly? If so, we will migrate to Sitecore 9, instead of spending a lot of time and energy on building custom code and items to make scheduled publishing work correctly.

I googled but couldn't find answers to my question.